# How do I add a clickable button to a textview that is clickable currently

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-listview

New to android trying to figure something out, any help appreciated.I have a textview which is currently clickable. I just need to put a clickable button background to it. This is my xml file: 
mainscreen.xml under layout

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:showDividers="middle" >


             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mainscreen_option"
                style="@style/TextView.MainscreenItem"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onMainscreenClicked"
                android:text="@string/nav_option"
                    />  
</LinearLayout>
```

and the selector class code where i have defined the button is under drawable folder :
bg_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_btn_active"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_btn_active" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_btn" />  
</selector>
```

and the corresponding javacode for the textview is :
mainscreennav.java

```
private void highlightMenuItem(){
TextView highlightedTextView = null;
final String activeFragmentTitle = getArguments().getString(ACTIVE_MENU_ITEM);
final Resources resources = Application.getAppResources();

if (resources.getString(R.string.nav_option_mainscreen).equals(FragmentTitle)) {
            highlightedTextView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.nav_option_mainscreen);
        } highlightedTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_orange));

    }
}
```

Can anyone guide me as to how I can convert this textview into a button such that both are clickable together and i can set the text margin in the button from left as certain dp's. 
Thanks in advance! Justin

Comment: You cannot "convert" something into another thing and have two things when you are done. Either you have a `TextView`, or you have a `Button` (after converting the `TextView` to a `Button`). Hence, there is no "both" that can be "clickable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

create a selector xml with your code and put in your drawable folder. I'll create a btn_custom.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_active" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_active" />
<item
     android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default" />
</selector>
```

Then, on your TextView:

```
<TextView android:text="MyButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_custom"
    android:padding="10dp"/>
```

On padding, you adjust your button padding.

On background, put the name of your selector (in my case, @drawable/btn_custom)

and your effect is already on.

Than, just register an onClickListener

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView myTextButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_button_id);
    myTextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ButtonClick", 200).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Ps: You can use your onClick method instead :P

Always remember: A Button is just a "styled" TextView.

This is the Android source code for Button class:

```
public class Button extends TextView {
    public Button(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.buttonStyle);
    }

    public Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
}
```

Yes, it's just that.

Comment: can you explain how to do that programmatically for the textview to appear as button

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you want to have clickable textview in front of the button?
If so create RelativeLayout instead of your LinearLayout, place your textview in front of button (or other way around according to your needs). And assign onClick for both of them.

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.